# Too many pattern attempts with no data connection? GS1

Tags: sim-unlocking, pattern-lock

So i locked myself out of my GalaxyS1(i9000)
I Have lots of stuff on there that i really need.
I have no wifi or data connection on,debugging is off,no root. only bluetooth on...
I know it seems like a lost cause but i really need a creative way in..
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

(If you have rooted device and activated adb from developer options on your phone previously. I have mentioned it here so it may help others.)

1. Download and install adb kits and driver from [here](http://adbshell.com/downloads)
2. Connect the phone via usb to your pc
3. In command prompt type the commands below

   - adb shell
   - cd data/system
   - su
   - rm *.key
4. Reboot.

---

**Disclaimer:** I'm not responsible if you brick your device by this method. Think carefully before doing it.

**Method 2:**

1. Download [Aroma File Manager](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1646108) and place it in your sdcard.(Rename it to update.zip if needed)
2. Go to recovery mode by powering off your device and press Volume up + Home then Power button.
3. Select update/install zip from sdcard and flash the aroma zip.
4. Go to `/data/system`
5. To remove pattern lock delete gesture.key and If you want to remove password, delete password.key
6. Reboot.

---

If these thing doesn't work I am afraid that you have to do a Hard Reset from Recovery.

**Suggestion:**
If you don't have privacy issue always backup your important documents(like:- contacts, messages etc.) in cloud or sync them with google's backup services.

Comment: OP already claims no debugging and no root, so M1 is DOA; M2 is actually very viable, but problem is he doesn't have a custom recovery _yet_, and if he's still on official ROM (Android 2.x), chances are the custom recoveries available (CWM 5.x) won't support Aroma. +1 for nice try.

Comment: If he doesn't have warranty he can flash a custom recovery in the first place.

Comment: where woulld i get CWM 5.x zip file?

Comment: You can get it  [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588649). Please try to google your prob , in most cases you will find an answer. @joeliy